# Flex stand-alone application

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I have built an authoring tool to create small stories which can be displayed in a story book format. I would like to publish each story as a stand-alone application (by simply pressing a button) and be able to send it via email. Does anybody has any idea how to create a stand-alone application in Flex by only clicking on a button?
Thank you in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anybody has any idea how to create a stand-alone application in
>   Flex by only clicking on a button?

It depends on the format you want the output to be in.  Assuming that you want a "Flash Platform" output; then I would have that button ping a remote service which can then use the Flex command line compiler to take your code and output a SWF or an AIR File.  With AIR you can even use captive runtime to create a native installer for Windows or Mac [or iOS or Android].  [You'll need to be on a Windows unit to create an .exe or a mac unit to create a dmg).

Just about every server side language has some type of PDF generation facility, so you could also use your application server and data from your app to create a PDF which I suspect will be much more palatable when you're sending it around via email.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I was thinking to create an .exe file. I would greatly appreciate if you can post an example (piece of code) for how to create an .exe file by clicking on a button.

Comment: @Aur I do not have an example ready to go.  If you want to hire me; I am available.  But, how about you try it; and post a new question if you have specific problems.